# getJSON works for some addresses, but not others

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, getjson

Having a strange problem. I'm using getJSON to retrieve information online using the following code:

```
$.getJSON("url", function(json) {
      $("#quote").html(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

Strangely, I have only been able to get the above code to work when I use https://api.whatdoestrumpthink.com/api/v1/quotes/random as the source. All other sources I have tried, such as http://quotes.rest/qod.json do not seem to return anything. I am currently using codepen to make my page.

I can retrieve quotes from the first URL perfectly and access everything how I'd like to, but not with anything else. I have tried using Get and ajax methods as well but to no avail. I'm relatively new to code so there must be something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your current host scheme `https` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what codepen uses. When I change http://quotes.rest/qod.json to https://quotes.rest/qod.json it does work! But when I use other https URLs such as https://www.freecodecamp.com/json/cats.json it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the server uses `https` protocol. Correct the URL and try again. Or provide logs if in case the request fails.

Comment: Ah! Yes that has now worked when I change https://quotes.rest/qod.json to https! However it still doesn't work when I use something like https://www.freecodecamp.com/json/cats.json.

Comment: Pass the url as `https://www.freecodecamp.com/json/cats.json`. The url you gave is also on `https`